# Annotate generic ES6 class with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, templates, generics, jsdoc

I want to document a generic map-like data structure with JSDoc. First of all, note that this structure does *not* extend `Map`.

A more general question would be: How do I annotate a generic ES6 class construct correctly?

Consider the following code. The marked piece of the annotation produces the error in the comment.

```
/** @type {MyMap<string, number>} */
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [js] Type 'MyMap' is not generic.
const map = new MyMap();
```

That’s the definition of `MyMap`:

```
// @ts-check

/**
 * @template K, V
 */
class MyMap {
  constructor() {
    this._map = new Map();
  }
}
```

What do I need to do so that `MyMap` counts as a generic type? How do I expose `K` and `V` as the generic types of the structure?

*(Note: I use Visual Studio Code to verify the annotations by adding `// @ts-check` to the top of my JavaScript file.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as stated in the question, the `@template` annotation to make the `MyMap` class generic is already correct. Below, `MyMap` has two generic types `Key` and `Value`. Those types can be used inside the class, for example, by setting the type of the instance property `this._map` to `/** @type {Map<Key, Value>} */`, etc. To demonstrate, I added two simple wrapper methods around `Map.prototype.set` and `Map.prototype.get` that rely on those types.

```js
// @ts-check

/**
 * @template Key, Value
 */
class MyMap {
  constructor() {
    /** @type {Map<Key, Value>} */ this._map = new Map();
  }

  /**
   * @param {Key} key 
   * @param {Value} value 
   */
  set(key, value) {
    this._map.set(key, value)
  }

  /**
   * @param {Key} key 
   * @returns {Value | undefined}
   */
  get(key) {
    return this._map.get(key)
  }
}

/** @type {MyMap<string, number>} */ const map = new MyMap();
map.set('key', 1)
map.get('key')
```